# Displaying an animated gif in pyside2

Tags: python, pyside2, qmediaplayer

I'm trying to display animated images using QMediaPlayer but I get a flash of the first frame, then just black.  It works fine for other movie formats, just not animated images.

I've got a program that can display images and movies.  I'm using a custom QWidget for displaying images.  I know it's common to use a QLabel but I wanted fine control over the image display.  For movies I'm using QMediaPlayer + QVideoWidget.  I show/hide each control as appropriate depending on the media type.  As I said, it works great for all formats except animated gifs.

I know that it's possible to display animated images using QMovie + QLabel.  I was hoping not to have to use three separate solutions for display, including one custom one for animated images.  It seems like the movie player should be able to play animated image formats.  Is there some way to make that work?

Comment: What are the advantages of using QMovie + QLabel with QMediaPlayer? On the other hand Qt Multimedia is a wrapper on libraries that handle each OS, for example in windows direct3d is used, in Linux it uses gstreamer, and therefore the limitations are not from Qt but from the libraries that Qt uses below.

Comment: As far as I understand it you don't use QMovie + QLabel with QMediaPlayer, you use one or the other typically.  QMovie handles simple animations without sound, while QMediaPlayer is a more full-featured media handler.  My hope is that I can use QMediaPlayer to do all animations and not having to split it up between the two.

Comment: ooops, I think I wrote my comment wrong, I meant: What are the advantages of using QMovie + QLabel **vs** QMediaPlayer?